# Calculate Age and convert Integer then create groupings or bins in Python

Tags: python

I'm newer to Python so don't beat me up too bad if this is a dumb question. This would have taken me minutes in SQL or SAS but I've spent hours in Python and am stuck. I have two date fields: a date of birth, and a claim date. First, I'm trying to determine the persons age at the time of the claim, then create groupings of ages such as (0-19,20-29, etc.)

## Convert date claimant born to datetime format and calc the age at the time of claim

```
wc2['Claimant_DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(wc2['Date_Claimant_Born'])
wc2['Date_of_Loss_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(wc2['Date_of_Loss'])
wc2['Age_at_Claim_Days'] = wc2['Date_of_Loss_dt'] - wc2['Claimant_DOB']
wc2['Age_at_Claim_Yrs'] = wc2["Age_at_Claim_Days"] / timedelta(days=365)
```

[Result from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfulP.png)

The problem I seem to be stuck with is that my calculated age is a float which I cannot group using an if statement and range as shown below.

```
if open1['Claimant_Age_Rounded'] in range(0,19.9999):
    open1['Age_Range'] = 'Under 20'
```

I get the error:
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

So, I tried converting to an integer and get an error there as well:
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

I should mention that, from reading other posts, I understand moving from float to int will degrade the accuracy in my data. For this specific example, I don't need precision. Just trying to get general look at it. I know it's my inexperience with Python but working with numbers seems overly complex at times in Python vs SQL and SAS. Hoping that as I work with it more, I will change my mind!

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just check `if 0 <= open1['...Age...'] < 20` without using range.

Comment: [Pandas.cut method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) is a great way to assign labels to numerical ranges.